# Is binary search thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 concurrent tasks each one separately work on different lists but `BinarySearch` method uses object of same class that implemented `IComparer` interface. Does `BinarySearch` works safe?

Thank you.

```
Parralle.Invoke
()=>
{
    list1.BinarySearch(item1,new class1());
},
()=
{
    list2.BinarySearch(item2,new class1());
});
```

Comment: As long as you don't modify any data, it's thread safe.  But having multiple tasks on a binary search is not going to provide you with any additional performance benefit.

Comment: If no items are updated (and the comparer doesn't brokenly use instance variables or other shared state), then there is no issue.

Comment: unless you're threads are touching the same part of Memory, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be safe

Comment: If your class's comparer isn't thread safe something is *seriously* wrong with your application.  That, or modifying the collection while this is executing (also a terrible idea) would be the only way to make this code not be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your binary searches are even interacting at all.

As far as I can tell, they're using completely different instances of whatever classes they're using.

Unless there's a chance that `BinarySearch` is going to touch a static variable, or if they're both going to touch the same instance of some class, I don't see any reason for you to worry.

Comment: How can `BinarySearch` touch a static variable?

Comment: @MartinMulder The custom comparer can.

Comment: True, but then it is not the `BinarySearch` which does that, it is the code of the programmer. And touching a static variable does not automatically make in thread unsafe.

Comment: @MartinMulder The question specifically specifies that a custom comparer will be used.  And even if it weren't, the class will need it's own `Compare` method to be usable, so somewhere there is custom comparison code, that's a given.  That code may not be thread safe.  It could be unsafe due to unsynchronized access to a static variable, or any number of other things.  The point remains that it has the potential to do something that creates a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

A `List<T>` being not really a list, but an array of variable size, uses an array as its backing store. The `List<T>` overloads for `BinarySearch()` are not documented as being thread-safe, nor are they documented as being thread-unsafe. Decompilation of the code shows them to do little but invoke the appropriate `System.Array.BinarySearch()` overload. The same holds true for those overloads: the documentation is silent on the topic of thread safety. Looking at the code, though show them to be thread-safe on the face of things.

**However...**

Much depends on the objects being compared and the `IComparer`/`IComparer<T>` implementation being used. It is possible (though it would seem unlikely) that something about them might be not thread-safe.

I think you're probably safe here, but it might be worth checking on things, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even if list1 and list2 are the same instance, all read operations on a `List<T>` are thread safe.

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19(v=vs.90).aspx

Be aware of the fact that even if `List<T>` is thread safe, your own code, like your own comparer, might not be thread safe. **If your code does not modify any (static) fields (or (static) automatic properties) or any other data like files, registry, database, etc., you are safe to use threading.**

Comment: Note that technically it's possible for the comparers to have side effects resulting in no-thread safe behavior.  It's unlikely, but you can't say that it's *impossible* for this code to have race conditions.

Comment: There are ways of creating race conditions in code beyond just the modification of static variables.  There could be fields of the custom comparer (although that's generally a terrible idea) there could be modifications of registry values, flat files, databases, web services, mutation of one or both of the actual objects being compared (probably one of the least absurd in this list, but still a terrible idea), etc.  (Sorry for being so pedantic, it's just that you edited your answer for the worst this last time; I'd just leave it as it was through the nebulous "something unsafe".)

Comment: I added "or any other data", which is pretty clear, I guess. And you are not striking me as pedantic, so no problem.